# Laravel 6 - Unique custom id doesn't increment after table get empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

**Current Situation**

I have custom unique increment makes the code looks like this

[image]

but when i make that table empty and add new value it looks like this

[image]

**Expected Situation**

after I made the table empty and make new input the `custom_id` should follow the `id`

[image]

**The Model**

```
    class Transaction_in extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'transaction_ins';
        protected $primaryKey = 'idTransactionsIN';
        public $timestamps = true;
        public $incrementing = false;
        protected $guarded = [];

    public static function getidTransactionsIN(){
        DB::table('transaction_ins')->orderBy('id','desc')->take(1)->get();
    }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'transaction_in_date' => 'required',
    ]);

    Transaction_in::getidTransactionsIN();

    $newtransaction_inId = Transaction_in::max('id') + 1;
    $Getnewtransaction_inId = sprintf('TIN%04d', $newtransaction_inId);

    $transaction_in = new Transaction_in();
    $transaction_in->idTransactionIN = $Getnewtransaction_inId;
    $transaction_in->date = $request->input('transaction_in_date');
    $transaction_in->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `custom_id` after creating model and it's a bit safer in case of many operations:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'transaction_in_date' => 'required',
    ]);


    $transaction_in = Transaction_in::create(['date' => $request->input('transaction_in_date')]);

    $transaction_in->update(['custom_id' => sprintf('TIN%04d', $transaction_in->id)]);
}
```

you should also just in case wrap it in [database transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#database-transactions).

Comment: what do you mean `wrap it in database transaction`?

Comment: @Aditya Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#database-transactions